# Is SharedPreferences's MODE_MULTI_PROCESS less safe than MODE_PRIVATE

Tags: android, process, sharedpreferences

The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) does not state anything regarding rather MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is safe (security-wise) or not.

So, is it safe? is there a reason not to use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This flag is not related to security, but to access concurency. It is less efficient but try to avoid problems caused by multiple process (from the same application) accessing the underlying file. If you don't write a multiprocess application, you don't need it. If you do, the documentation suggest to use other inter-process communication. The documentation advise against it for performance reasons, not security.

So `MODE_PRIVATE` / `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` / `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` on one hand and `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` on the other are orthogonal flags. If you open the `SharedPreferences` with :

- `MODE_PRIVATE` --> secure
- `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`  --> insecure
- `MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` --> secure
- `MODE_WORLD_READABLE | MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` --> insecure

and as `MODE_PRIVATE` has a value of 0 : `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` is equivalent to `MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` (i.e. secure)

Actually the only use in the source of `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` is in the `ContextImpl` class :

```
@Override
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) {
    SharedPreferencesImpl sp;
    synchronized (sSharedPrefs) {
        sp = sSharedPrefs.get(name);
        if (sp == null) {
            File prefsFile = getSharedPrefsFile(name);
            sp = new SharedPreferencesImpl(prefsFile, mode);
            sSharedPrefs.put(name, sp);
            return sp;
        }
    }
    if ((mode & Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) != 0 ||
        getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // If somebody else (some other process) changed the prefs
        // file behind our back, we reload it.  This has been the
        // historical (if undocumented) behavior.
        sp.startReloadIfChangedUnexpectedly();
    }
    return sp;
}
```

Comment: I agree that this is what the documentation says, but the fast that security is not mentioned in it does not mean that it is not an issue

Comment: added some explanation

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not safe.

The documentation also states: "This was the legacy (but undocumented) behavior in and before Gingerbread (Android 2.3) and this flag is implied when targetting such releases. For applications targetting SDK versions greater than Android 2.3, this flag must be explicitly set if desired." This seems to be an old feature that they do not encourage to use.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the case... accessing shared prefs across processes is very handy at times. The fact it is not the default behaviour anymore does not imply that it is not safe

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any mechanism then to prevent access by other foreign processes... Other than not knowing the name....

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanism to prevent access from foreign processes: SharedPreferences is app-private. The Android security model prevents other apps from getting to the file, even if they can someone figure out its name (which believe me is not easy).

Comment: So I should feel safe to save sensitive data using MODE_MULTI_PROCESS? Is there some kind of reference to that mechanism in Android's documentation?